# accessing colors from a ggtheme theme in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have a pretty nice little plot I've made with ggplot and it looks great. I have some bars and then some crossbars. I'm using the `theme_economist()` from the `ggthemes` package and I'd like to make the bars all one color from that theme and the crossbars a contrasting color. But I can't figure out how to reach into the theme and grab out a couple of colors for these elements. I can change them to a named color and I can change them to a specific hex color, but it seems like I should be able to reach into the theme and say, "gimme two contrasting colors from this theme!" How do I do that?

Here's a reprex showing what I have...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

prices <- data.frame(year=2001:2010, 
                     price=rnorm(10))
additional_junk <- data.frame(year=2001:2010, 
                              thing=rnorm(10))

g_price <- ggplot() + theme_economist() + 
  scale_fill_economist() + 
  scale_colour_economist() +
  geom_bar(aes(y = price , x = year), 
           data = prices, stat="identity") +
  geom_crossbar(data=additional_junk, aes(x=year, y=thing, 
                                        ymin=0, ymax=0) 
  ) 
g_price
```

[image]

Comment: Here is the code on GitHub: https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes/blob/master/R/economist.R

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ggthemes` includes a list object `ggthemes_data` with various palettes and other data used by the package (see below). You could choose from among those colors.

```
library(ggthemes)

ggthemes_data$economist
```

> ```
> $bg
>       ebg     edkbg       red    ltgray    dkgray 
> "#d5e4eb" "#c3d6df" "#ed111a" "#ebebeb" "#c9c9c9" 
>
> $fg
>   blue_gray   blue_dark green_light    blue_mid  blue_light  green_dark        gray  blue_light    red_dark   red_light 
>   "#6794a7"   "#014d64"   "#76c0c1"   "#01a2d9"   "#7ad2f6"   "#00887d"   "#adadad"   "#7bd3f6"   "#7c260b"   "#ee8f71" 
> green_light       brown 
>   "#76c0c1"   "#a18376" 
>
> $stata
> $stata$bg
>       ebg     edkbg 
> "#C6D3DF" "#B2BFCB" 
>
> $stata$fg
>   edkblue  emidblue   eltblue   emerald     erose    ebblue  eltgreen     stone      navy    maroon     brown  lavender 
> "#3E647D" "#7B92A8" "#82C0E9" "#2D6D66" "#BFA19C" "#008BBC" "#97B6B0" "#D7D29E" "#1A476F" "#90353B" "#9C8847" "#938DD2" 
>      teal cranberry     khaki 
> "#6E8E84" "#C10534" "#CAC27E"
> ```

In addition, as noted by the commenters, you can generate palettes with `economist_pal()`, for example, `economist_pal()(2)` or `economist_pal(stata=TRUE)(3)`.

```
library(scales)

show_col(economist_pal()(9))
```

[image]

```
show_col(economist_pal(stata=TRUE)(9))
```

[image]